# Swift: generic init inside a non generic struct

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Ok, I'll try to explain you what I'm trying to get with a minimum viable example: I'd like to have a struct like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let aBool: Bool
    let aInt: Int
    let aHashable: Hashable?
}
```

but of course this can't be done because:

> Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

and this is fine. I can get what I want this way:

```
struct MyStruct<T> where T: Hashable {
    let aBool: Bool
    let aInt: Int
    let aHashable: T?
}
```

But I want my struct to have two init this way:

```
struct MyStruct<T> where T: Hashable {
    let aBool: Bool
    let aInt: Int
    let aHashable: T?

    init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int) {
        self.init(aBool: aBool, aInt: aInt, aHashable: nil)
    }

    init(aHashable: T?) {
        self.init(aBool: false, aInt: 0, aHashable: aHashable)
    }

    private init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int, aHashable: T?) {
        self.aBool = aBool
        self.aInt = aInt
        self.aHashable = aHashable
    }
}
```

And if I try to init the struct like this:

```
let myStruct = MyStruct(aBool: true, aInt: 10)
```

I get an error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

The problem is that even if I turn the struct into a non generic struct (with a couple of generic init):

```
struct MyStruct {
    let aBool: Bool
    let aInt: Int
    let aHashable: T?

    init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int) {
        self.init(aBool: aBool, aInt: aInt, aHashable: nil)
    }

    init<T>(aHashable: T?) where T: Hashable {
        self.init(aBool: false, aInt: 0, aHashable: aHashable)
    }

    private init<T>(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int, aHashable: T?) where T: Hashable {
        self.aBool = aBool
        self.aInt = aInt
        self.aHashable = aHashable
    }
}
```

I still get an error. This time on the `let aHashable: T?` stored property:

> Use of undeclared type 'T'

What's the right way to get what I want? Thank you.

Comment: You would have to explicitly declare the generic type when calling your initializer: `MyStruct<Something>(aBool: true, aInt: 10)`.  Depending on how you're actually using this object it might work for you to keep it not generic and use `AnyHashable?` as the type for your property

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you. I don't really like having to specify the type like this `MyStruct<Something>(aBool: true, aInt: 10)`. It's really weird to force the user of this "api" to specify a random type that conforms to Hashable just to silence the problem. AnyHashable might be a solution, but I guess it could be a solution that doesn't involve type erasure. If I'm not wrong I've already seen some API from Apple doing the same.

Comment: What *exactly* are you tryign to achieve by this? Why is `false`/`0` a valid substitute for a hashable thing? There's a lot of important back story here.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica It's not easy to explain exactly what I need (that's why I created this minimum example). But I just found an API from Apple that does exactly what I'd like to do. Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink it has several `init`. For example: `init(destinationName: String, isActive: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)`  and  `init<V>(destination: Destination, tag: V, selection: Binding<V?>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) where V : Hashable` The second one is generic, but the main Struct (NavigationLink) is not.

Comment: The reason I'm pressing for the motivation here is because I very highly suspect this is an X/Y problem. I suspect your example has distilled down too much. The example of `NavigationLink` isn't exactly relevant, because it doesn't store a value of a generic type (as is the case here with `aHashable: T`). There's nothing special about a non-generic type having a generic func/init, and that's just what `NavigationLInk` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `T` you want in this case is `Never`, since it can never have a value. To define that kind of init, you need to constrain it in  an extension like this:

```
extension MyStruct where T == Never {
    init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int) {
        self.init(aBool: aBool, aInt: aInt, aHashable: nil)
    }
}
```

IMO, Swift should also allow this as:

```
init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int) where T == Never {...}
```

But that's not currently legal Swift. You have to put it in an extension. It's just a syntax issue.

For completeness, here's the full code:

```
struct MyStruct<T> where T: Hashable {
    let aBool: Bool
    let aInt: Int
    let aHashable: T?

    init(aHashable: T?) {
        self.init(aBool: false, aInt: 0, aHashable: aHashable)
    }

    private init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int, aHashable: T?) {
        self.aBool = aBool
        self.aInt = aInt
        self.aHashable = aHashable
    }
}

extension MyStruct where T == Never {
    init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int) {
        self.init(aBool: aBool, aInt: aInt, aHashable: nil)
    }
}

let myStruct = MyStruct(aBool: true, aInt: 10)
```

Comment: Huh, this works, but `Never` doesn't explicitly conform to `Hashable`. Compiler magic?

Comment: Never does explicitly conform to Hashable. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c1bc32cfb405ed28e1113de7ac74c9c017116a9e/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L40

Comment: Is that Swift file a *real* Swift file, or just stubs of what the compiler's behaviour would look like if expressed in Swift? Because I see functions with missing returns, `Hashable` conformance with no actual conforming implemented methods, etc. I also just noticed that the apple docs list conformances at the bottom, not with the usual colon notation that Swift uses. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/never

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica From the Hashable docs: "When you define an enumeration without associated values, it gains Hashable conformance automatically." `Never` is an enum without associated values, so it's no special case for it to conform.

Comment: Ah yes. That explains that. How about the missing return value in this `Bool`-returning `<` operator? https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c1bc32cfb405ed28e1113de7ac74c9c017116a9e/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L36-L37

Comment: @RobNapier thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That's a general feature of uninhabited types. Functions that require an uninhabited type (such as Never) do not have to have an implementation since they can't be called. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/b31c66ceb70f0e319c6f848729d0e98a

Comment: @RobNapier Wow, that's neat! I knew they could never be called, but I still thought it would require a `fatalError` or a dummy return  in the body, or something along those lines

Comment: There are so many reasons Never is my favorite stdlib type. :D

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
struct MyStruct<T: Hashable> {
    let aBool: Bool
    let aInt: Int
    let aHashable: T?

    init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int) {
        self.init(aBool: aBool, aInt: aInt, aHashable: nil)
    }

    init(aHashable: T?) {
        self.init(aBool: false, aInt: 0, aHashable: aHashable)
    }

    private init(aBool: Bool, aInt: Int, aHashable: T?) {
        self.aBool = aBool
        self.aInt = aInt
        self.aHashable = aHashable
    }
}
```

than

```
let myStruct = MyStruct<'Your Hashable Type'>(aBool: true, aInt: 10)
```